# Apollo-client local state cache race condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

So I have been trying to use apollo-boost in a React app to use the cache to manage my client state using @client directives on queries but I have been having some issues.

Basically I'm using writeQuery() to write a boolean to my local app state in a Component (let's call it component A) and want to get that value in another Component (let's call it component B) using readQuery() inside the componentDidUpdate method. The thing is, readQuery() in Component B is running before writeQuery in Component A sets the value in the cache/local state so the value read by Component B comes out wrong.

I've confirmed this by using setTimeout to delay the readQuery() and indeed after using the timeout, the value is correct, but this solution can't be trusted, I'm probably not aware of something in Apollo Client because this functionality is pretty basic for local state management. Any Tips?

I believe that in Redux this is solved because the state is being injected to props, which makes the component update, so being that Component A is the one that changes the state, component B wouldn't even have to use componentDidUpdate to get the new value, since the state would be injected and Component B would get updated with the correct value.

Any help would be appreciated, sorry if I didn't make myself clear!

EDIT: The writeQuery() is being used inside a Mutation resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Methods like `readQuery` and `writeQuery` are meant to be used to read and modify the cache inside of mutations. In general, they should not be used inside of components directly. By calling `readQuery`, you are only fetching the data from the cache once. Instead, you should utilize a `Query` component.

```
const TODO_QUERY = gql`
  query GetTodos {
    todos @client {
      id
      text
      completed
    }
  }
`

<Query query={TODO_QUERY}>
  {({ data }) => {
    if (data.todos) return <ToDoListComponent todos={data.todos}/>
    return null
  }}
</Query>
```

The `Query` component subscribes to relevant changes to the cache, so the value of `data` will update when your cache does.

Similarly, you should create appropriate mutations for whatever changes to the cache you're going to make, and then utilize a `Mutation` component to actually mutate the cache.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  clientState: {
    defaults: {
      todos: []
    },
    resolvers: {
      Mutation: {
        addTodo: (_, { text }, { cache }) => {
          const previous = cache.readQuery({ query: TODO_QUERY })
          const newTodo = { id: nextTodoId++, text, completed: false, __typename: 'TodoItem' }
          const data = {
            todos: previous.todos.concat([newTodo]),
          }

          cache.writeQuery({ query, data })
          return newTodo
        },
      },
    }
  }
})

<Mutation mutation={ADD_TODO}>
  {(addTodo) => (
    // use addTodo to mutate the cache asynchronously
  )}
</Mutation>
```

Please review [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/state.html) for more details.

Comment: Yes sorry I made myself unclear, I am actually using the writeQuery inside a Mutation, the readQuery though, is not being used inside a Query Component. What is the best practice if I need to access the cache (be it to write or read) outside the render method?

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @milanesa What are you trying to do? You could use the `graphql` HOC instead of the `Query` component, but the `Query` component is the preferred way of doing things. The render props pattern sometimes forces you to restructure your components, but I'm fairly sure you can still use it for whatever you're trying to do. It would be helpful if you edited your question with the relevant code and a further explanation of what you're trying to actually achieve.

Comment: Sure Daniel, I cant upload the code actually but what I'm trying to do is the following. I'm using react-navigation on a tab where I have a prop which tells if the screen is focused or not, I want to store that value in order to use it in another component and after reading that value in this component I need to setState (which is a bad practice to do inside a render method).
In another case I need to use it inside a HOC I created.

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, it's not always possible, but when posting question on SO, it's good to try to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), even if it's not you're actual production code.

Comment: I understand. I can't in this case, sorry :( Appreciate your help!